# angular 4 execute function when user leave

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-ui-router

I do some functions when user load a component and create data I create function clear and delete what I did but need load this function when user refresh or change a route or close the page I'm used HashLocationStrategy on routes !

Comment: use ngOnDestroy https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-hooks

Comment: it's working with move between routes but when i do refresh doesn't work !

Comment: Bind @HostListener window:onbeforeunload or window:onunload